# Android Lint only want to check my project, not library projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, lint

I've found a solution to this problem if I'm using Eclipse.

[image: a]

However, I can't find this in Android Studio (version 1.0). When I'm building my project, I'm currently getting multiple errors from the appcompat_v7 library and many more warnings as well. I just want to make Lint skip testing all libraries.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for some time, I found the answer in the official lint documentation on http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html#studio_config

> Module and file-specific preferences
>
> 1. Run the lint tool on your module by right-clicking on your module
>      folder or file in the Project View and selecting Analyze > Inspect
>      Code. This displays the lint inspection results with a list of issues
>      that lint detected in your module.
> 2. From the Lint Warnings view, use
>      the toolbar options to configure lint preferences for individual
>      modules and files, and set the issue display options.